# How do you make Apache2 use/respond only to IP address

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web-server, hostname

I have an apache2 server that is behind a firewall.  The external address is 24.89.xxx.xxx and the internal address is 10.10.58.1

The server's hostname is 'myhost'.  I don't have a DNS entry for the 24.89.xxx.xxx address because it's not live yet.  The domain name that will resolve to it is currently in use for the existing site.

I would like the web-dev team to be able to access the site via the 24.89.xxx.xxx address.  However, whenever they view the site, all the URLs get the local hostname inserted into them.

So, `<a href="index.php?id=9">Link</a>` produces a URL of `http://myhost/index.php?id=9`  However, I would like it to produce a URL of `http://24.89.xxx.xxx/index.php?id=9`

Apache is installed on Debian Lenny.  I'm using the "default" site.  I've tried variations of setting the NamedVirtualHost to the IP, ServerName to the IP, UseCanonicalName off, VirualHost, etc...  Everything I do produces no change whatsoever.  Yes, I'm reloading the config each time.

I've also tried cutting out the firewall, and I get the same result.  I've also made a bunch of changes to the /etc/hosts file.

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.10.58.1      myhost
24.89.xxx.xxx   www.inusedomain.org
```

Comment: This is a programming question, not a sysadmin one.

Comment: I beg to differ, considering I'm not doing any programming.

Comment: how is that ever a programming question?

Comment: It's a programming question because this is an issue with his content producing system, not apache.  However, it could be easily mis-identified as a server issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading more carefully, I think this might be a php issue.  Generally, you need to set some sort of '**base URL**' in the config for a website, so php knows how to create all of the links ("Over write the urls"). **Look for a config.php**, or something like that in the root dir of the website.

If you have bad developers, it might be not in a single variable, and all over the place.  To find this, or maybe to find it in a single location, use `grep -Ri --include='*.php*' 'localhost' *`, changing localhost to whatever it is that is currently being overwritten.

Not a Complete Answer:
I am not entirely sure, but I think I remember that binding a virtual host to specific IP, or changing the listen directive requried a total restart, not just a graceful restart or a configuration reload.

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee that the problem isn't apache.  You should be looking at whatever is producing your html content... ie. php, etc.